# Textview display in Android from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, textview

In my application I have one `listview`, in that I am displaying data from database.

Following is my code:

```
for(int i=1;i<=db.getAllTitles().getCount();i++)
              {
                 String cat=db.getTitle(i).getString(5).toString();
                 Cursor c = db.gethouseholdTitle();
                  startManagingCursor(c); 
                 if(cat.equals("Income"))
                 {  
//                   System.out.println("inside if="+select);
//                   Cursor cin = db.income();
                      from = new String[] { db.KEY_INCOME,db.KEY_DESC,db.KEY_CATEGORY,db.KEY_QUANTITY,db.KEY_TOTAL};
                      to = new int[] {R.id.text1 ,R.id.text3,R.id.text5,R.id.text7,R.id.text9};
                     SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
                                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnview, c, from, to);
                    //  System.out.println("notes="+notes.getCount());
                    //  setListAdapter(notes);    
                       lv.setAdapter(notes);  
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     String catexp=db.getTitle(i).getString(5).toString();
                     Cursor cexp = db.gethouseholdTitleExp();
                    System.out.println("inside else="+cexp.getCount());
                     from = new String[] { db.KEY_INCOME,db.KEY_DESC,db.KEY_CATEGORY,db.KEY_QUANTITY,db.KEY_TOTAL};
                     to = new int[] {R.id.text2 ,R.id.text4,R.id.text6,R.id.text8,R.id.text10};
                    SimpleCursorAdapter notesexp =
                            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnview, cexp, from, to);
                //  System.out.println("notes="+notes.getCount());
                //  setListAdapter(notes);    
                   lv.setAdapter(notesexp);  
                 }                   

              }
```

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">         

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"      
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="Price:"/> 

      <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"     
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"          
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text4"      
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"       
        android:layout_weight="1"/>  

       <TextView android:id="@+id/text5"            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <TextView android:id="@+id/text6"        
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"       
        android:layout_weight="1"/>  

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text7"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

         <TextView android:id="@+id/text8"      
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"       
        android:layout_weight="1"/>  

          <TextView android:id="@+id/text9"         
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

          <TextView android:id="@+id/text10"        
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"       
        android:layout_weight="1"/>  

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> 

</LinearLayout>..
```

In this, only `income` data get displayed. Nothing is displaying for `expense`. I checked database for expense count, it gives exact count. So data is present in database, but not get displayed. Is there any problem in my design?

Answer (score 0):

In listview only possible to load one items only. Not supported to load more than one. Please try to display via grid view with the same syntax. If you want to try in list view then you should add the columns via Base adapter to list view.
Please see the given tutorial link for base adapter.It will help you,
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327

http://pradeep-sharma.com/blog/android-custom-listview-baseadapter-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Venkatesh..How can i fill two values separately in the grid view.

Comment: Ok . I am add the Answer for add the values into gridview.Please see the answer. It might be help you.

Comment: Do you get the answer or not?

Comment: Did you try my codings?What's the problem comes?

Comment: If you tried my coding then your result will be in above figure.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the Layout by this given coding,

### showlist.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Show">
    <TextView android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:textColor="#ff8000"
        android:id="@+id/Entry"  android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="left"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:textColor="#ff8000"
        android:id="@+id/sales"  android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right" />
</TableRow>
```

You can add the any no of textview here,I think you want to add four textview so you has to change the textview width as 25dp.

### GridView set:

Then set simplecursoradapter for gridview coding as given

```
       ada=new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.showlist, mon,new String[] { cname, "_id" }, new int[] { R.id.Entry,R.id.sales }) 

   gridview.setadapter(ada);

   //It will work well.
```

The main thing is you should create the gridview with mention the column is one.

### The Result will be

[image]