# Gridview layout in android

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I want to display a gridview in my application.My gridview should look like as a table in database(how many columns and how many rows).Should resemble like database.But i am having some collapsed format not looking nice.Please help me.

My main.xml:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1view" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dip" />
```

My Layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">           

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"       
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text5"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text7"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text9"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please detail your issue

Comment: what is the issue, post more information.

Comment: you want gridview having 5 columns of only textviews??

Comment: Same problem posted here

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426869/textview-dispaly-in-android/11427430#11427430>

Comment: Hi sunil.My issue is i want to display data from database as it looks like in database.that is i have to divide into 5 columns and have to fill the data.Please assume any database like that format i want..

Comment: your xml layout is not clear,first of all any text is not there and by keeping text,they all reside horizontally without having some space betwwen them

Comment: But still it is not clear to me that how u want to show data in grid?? you want that there should 5 text in every row of grid??

Comment: Exactly that is AkashG ..I want to show 5 columns and row is based on my database.

Comment: Create custom adapter class extending BaseAdapter and inflate the above xml file you created in it.Define textview in Holder class and set its value from database

Comment: Actually i am setting this xml file in baseadapter ..but what is that holder class..

Answer (score 1):

I had similar kind of screen so,you can make use of some code below.

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /**
     * Array list to hold assets which need to be displayed
     */
    ArrayList<Asset> itemList;

    /**
     * Context: Interface to global information about an application
     * environment.
     */
    public Activity context;

    /**
     * Layout inflater to inflate view of each row of the list from the layout
     * xml
     */
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    /**
     * @param context
     *            : Context: Interface to global information about an
     *            application environment.
     * @param itemList
     *            : arraylist to hold asset which need to be displayed in list
     */
    public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Asset> itemList) {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;

        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    // @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    public int getCount() {
        if (itemList != null) {
            return itemList.size();
        }else return 0;
    }

    // @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
     */
    public Object getItem(int position) {   
        if(itemList != null){
            return itemList.get(position);
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }

    // @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * @author asadafale class to create view of each row in the list
     */
    public static class ViewHolder {

        /**
         * displays name of asset
         */
        TextView txtVw_name;
        /**
         * displays serial no of asset
         */
        TextView txtVw_sno;
        /**
         * displays type of asset
         */
        TextView txtVw_type;

    }

    // @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     * android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

            holder.txtVw_name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.txtVw_sno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sno);
            holder.txtVw_type = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_type);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        // set selected item
        LinearLayout activeItem = (LinearLayout) convertView;

        if (position == SearchAssetActivity.selectedItem) {
            activeItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            // for focus on it
            int top = (activeItem == null) ? 0 : activeItem.getTop();
            ((ListView) parent).setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
        } else {
            activeItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        Asset bean = (Asset) itemList.get(position);

        holder.txtVw_name.setText(bean.getAssetName());
        holder.txtVw_sno.setText(bean.getSno());
        holder.txtVw_type.setText(bean.getAssetType());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

[image]

Part of my screen looks similar like what you want.

Here's my layout in xml  :

```
<LinearLayout        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey05"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sno"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Serial No."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_type"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I knew that I want to display 3 columns only. You can have those many textview defined in your layout.xml. In your case I believe you will know number of columns on the fly so you will need some kind of an array of `TextView`s to do it dynamically which can't be done through xml. You will have to define an array of `TextView`s in your adapter class and on the fly you can initialize depending on the data coming from database.
Hope you got what I wanted to convey. Let me know if you need more help designing that, once you get started. :)

Comment: Thanks Abhilasha..Whether it is possible to 5 columns in xml file itself.Because u r doing manually in code.But i want that in design itself...Is it possible??